# Scikit-learn Ridge classifier: extracting class probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

I'm currently using sklearn's Ridge classifier, and am looking to ensemble this classifier with classifiers from sklearn and other libraries.  In order to do this, it would be ideal to extract the probability that a given input belongs to each class in a list of classes.  Currently, I'm zipping the classes with the output of model.decision_function(x), but this returns the distance from the hyperplane as opposed to a straightforward probability.
These distance values vary from around -1 to around 1.

```
distances = dict(zip(clf.classes_, clf.decision_function(x)[0]))
```

How can I convert these distances to a more concrete set of probabilities (a series of positive values that sum to 1)?  I'm looking for something like `clf.predict_proba()` that is implemented for the SVC in sklearn.

Comment: There is no `predict_proba` on `RidgeClassifier` because it's not easily interpreted as a probability model, AFAIK. A logistic transform or just thresholding at [-1, 1] and mapping that to [0, 1] are possible, but both are hacks.

Comment: Yeah, the best I could do was take the softmax of the decision function, but at least that a) maintains relative ordering and b) makes ensembling simpler.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Further exploration lead to using the softmax function.

```
d = clf.decision_function(x)[0]
probs = np.exp(d) / np.sum(np.exp(d))
```

This guarantees a 0-1 bounded distribution that sums to 1.

Answer (score 12):

A little look at the source code of `predict` shows that `decision_function` is in fact the logit-transform of the actual class probabilities, i.e., if `decision funciton` is `f`, then the class probability of `class 1` is `exp(f) / (1 + exp(f))`. This translates to following check in the sklearn source:

```
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
    if len(scores.shape) == 1:
        indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)
    else:
        indices = scores.argmax(axis=1)
    return self.classes_[indices]
```

If you observe this check, it tells you that if decision function is greater than zero, then predict class 1, otherwise predict class 0 - a classical logit approach.

So, you will have to turn the decision function into something like:

```
d = clf.decision_function(x)[0]
probs = numpy.exp(d) / (1 + numpy.exp(d))
```

And then take appropriate `zip` etc.

Comment: 1) Seems similar to softmax

2) Although the outputs of `np.exp(d) / (1 + np.exp(d))` are bounded in the 0 - 1 range, they aren't normalized and don't seem to correspond to the proper distances to the plane.  In other words, taking the argmax of the decision function scores doesn't return the same result as taking the argmax of `np.exp(d) / (1 + np.exp(d))`.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Never mind, I think I've answered my own question. I believe the proper solution to the problem is to literally apply softmax: `np.exp(d) / np.sum(np.exp(d))`.  You pointed me in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions provided here didn't work for me. I think the `softmax` function is the correct solution, so I extended RidgeClassifierCV class with a `predict_proba` method similar to [LogisticRegressionCV](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13a/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py#L1437)

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import softmax
class RidgeClassifierCVwithProba(RidgeClassifierCV):
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        d = self.decision_function(X)
        d_2d = np.c_[-d, d]
        return softmax(d_2d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This version is based on [Emanuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66781774). It is agnostic to whether the target is binary or multiclass. It incorporates a temperature hyperparameter that scales the logits before applying the softmax function.

```
class RidgeClassifierWithProba(RidgeClassifier):
    def __init__(self, temperature=1.0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.temperature = temperature

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        d = self.decision_function(X) / self.temperature
        if len(d.shape) == 1:
            d = np.c_[-d, d]
        return softmax(d)
```