# Plotting ROC curve for RidgeClassifier in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, roc, auc

I want to plot the ROC curve for the `RidgeClassifier`. But the code comes with an error: I googled for solutions and it comes up to change `predict_proba` to `predict`, but it does not work!

```
predY = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'RidgeClassifier' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

This is what I get with `predict`:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scikit-learn Ridge classifier: extracting class probabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538080/scikit-learn-ridge-classifier-extracting-class-probabilities)

Comment: @MauraPintor Do you mean: d = classifier.decision_function(X)[0]
predY = np.exp(d) / np.sum(np.exp(d))?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that not all scikit-learn classifiers have a `predict_proba` method, since there is not always a reasonable definition of computed probability for these models. In this case, try with the `decision_function` method instead:

```
confidence = classifier.decision_function(X_test)
```

Comment: Do you mean: predY = confidence?

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick. More info on how that is computed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifier.decision_function).

Comment: Hmmm. . . what shape is `predY`? Maybe try either `predY = predY.flatten()` or `predY = predY[:, 1]` depending on whether the number of columns is 1 or 2.

Comment: Still the same error. Unlike `predY` for other classifiers, in this case `predY` contains negative values.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifier), a `Ridge.Classifier` has no `predict_proba` attribute. This must be because the object automatically picks a threshold during the fit process.

Given the documentation, I believe there is no way to plot a ROC curve for this model. Fortunately, you can use `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` and set `penalty='l2'`. By doing so, you are setting the same optimization problem considered by a `RidgeClassifier`.

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

classifier = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')
classifier.fit(X, y)
predY = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Now you can pass `predY` to `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`.

Comment: I used your code, but it comes with an error:
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: My bad! I believe I had an unmatched  `)`. Does it work now?

Comment: I've suggested an edition that works for me. So using `LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')` will lead to same result as `RidgeClassifier`?

Comment: Yes, it should give you the same result. Just note that the L2 regression returns probabilities, so each threshold you choose will yield a new array of predicted classes. For example, imagine you have `predY = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`. If you set a threshold of `0.2` then the predicted classes will be `[0, 1, 1, 1]`. If you set a threshold of `0.3`, the predicted classes will be `[0, 0, 1, 1]`.